# How to Refresh NPM files

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've been getting some syntax errors and i've removed all the code in the file, but the react app is showing the same compile errors and there is no use of npm run build even the build fails because of the syntax error which i removed already. What might be the problem?

Comment: We can't know the problem if you don't post any code or any error messages. Consider making a codesandbox to demonstrate the issue too.

Comment: Delete node_modules, then do npm install. ```rm -rf node_modules``` ```npm install```